# Mod rewrite enabled but not working in Apache

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, virtualhost

I currently use an iMac running Mavericks for development at work. I use the built in version of Apache and installed MySQL using homebrew when I first got the machine. Recently I had an issue where one of my virtual hosts was not working as expected and I ended up using Virtual Host X's restore command to wipe out my virtual hosts and start again.

I managed to get my vhosts working again but since then have noticed that mod_rewrite, although enabled, is not working. If I go to http://mywebsite.local/events I get an error
**"Not Found -The requested URL /events was not found on this server."** but if I go to http://mywebsite.local/index.php/events view the page fine.

I think restoring using Virtual Host X may have corrupted something in my Apache set up as the restore command does have this warning:

**"Backup files contain all of your VirtualHostX data as well as copies of your web        configuration files. Restoring a backup will replace those files and your current data (virtual hosts, domain details, etc) with the previously backed up data."**

Here is a copy of my vhost settings for one of the sites I'm having issues with:

```
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|ttf|woff)$ /index.php
```

I first experienced this issue on Mountain Lion but have since upgraded to Mavericks hoping it would fix the issue but to no avail.

Any help would be great. If the issue can't easily be solved anyone with any advice about how to completely rid your machine of Apache and start again would also be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answer but unfortunately it didn't work out. However I am pleased to say the issue is now sorted. I pasted in your code and it stopped my virtual host from running altogether. I needed to paste my original code back in so copied and pasted it back in from this post in Stack Overflow and restarted Apache. I clicked on a few links and the rewrites are now working.

I'm guessing that there were some hidden characters which were causing the issue which were eradicated when I pasted the code back in.

I hope this helps someone as it was very annoying.

Comment: "it stopped my virtual host from running altogether.", it's very strange.

Answer (score 0):

This should be used in Debian Apache2:

```
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|ttf|woff)$ /index.php [L]
```